# How can I get the smaller side of a 2 digit number in assembly?

Tags: assembly, dosbox

I need to get one of the digit (the left digit in this case) and only that digit, for example if I have a 25 in a variable how can I get only the five to a register?

Comment: Divide by 10 and use the remainder.

Comment: How is the **5** from the number **25** the *left* digit?